# Desaparecer un elemento al hacer clic en otro Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Necesito desaparecer un elemento cuando se hace clic en un enlace (etiqueta a), son un total de tres botones y necesito que cuando se le haga clic a uno de ellos desaparezca la burbuja de dialogo y texto del botón que este activo en un inicio para que aparezca la burbuja de dialogo y texto del botón al que se le este dando clic, dejo los códigos respectivos para que puedan orientarse en el funcionamiento que le quiero dar y la idea que tengo, de antemano muchas gracias.

```js
if($(".comunication-box").length){
  $(".comunication-box .comunication-buttons .tabs1").on("click", function(i){
         i.preventDefault();

           var target = $($(this).attr("data-target"));

           if ($(target).is(":visible")) {
              return false;
           } else {
               target.parents(".comunication-buttons").find(".inline").find(".active").removeClass("active");
               $(target).addClass("active");
               target.parents(".comunication-box").find(".comunication-content").find(".content").removeClass("vissible");
               $(target).addClass("vissible");
               target.parents(".comunication-box").find(".comunication-content").find(".content").find(".col-md-12").find(".row").find("inline").find("dialog").removeClass("not-hidden");
               $(target).addClass("not-hidden");

        }
    });
}
```

```css
.not-hidden{
       visibility: visible!important;
    }
    .vissible{
       display: block!important;
       transition-delay: 1s;
       transition-duration: 2s;
       transition-property: width;
       transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
    .content{
       display: none;
    }
    .inline{
       display: inline-block;
    }
    .comunication-buttons{
       position: relative;
       top: 50px;
       right: 46px;
    }
    .dialog{
       visibility: hidden;
       position: absolute;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
       border: 1px solid grey;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 0 14px;
       padding-bottom: 24px;
       bottom: 8px;
       right: 22px;
       height: 20px;
       width: 178px;
       border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .dialog::after{
       content: "";
       display: block;
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       color: #000;
       border-left: 30px solid;
       border-top: 15px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
       z-index: -6;
       transform: rotate(90deg);
       margin-left: 50px;
       margin-top: 4px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="general/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="general/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="comunication-box">
       <div class="comunication-buttons">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="inline active">
                <a href="#" class="comunicacion btn-dialog" data-target="phone">
                   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                </a>
             </div>
             <div class="inline">
                <a href="#" class="comunicacion btn-dialog active" data-target="map">
                   <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt borde-izq"></i>
                </a>
             </div>
             <div class="inline">
                <a href="#" class="comunicacion btn-dialog tablinks" data-target="mail">
                   <i class="far fa-envelope borde-izq"></i>
                </a>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="comunication-content">
          <div class="content" id="phone">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="inline">
                      <div class="dialog dialog-cel">
                         <p>99324819110</p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content vissible" id="map">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                      <div class="dialog not-hidden">
                         <p>Saudi Arabia .Alreyadah</p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content" id="mail">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                   </div>
                   <div class="inline">
                      <div class="dialog dialog-message">
                         <p>Contact us!</p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="general/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="general/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="general/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="general/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</html>
```

**NOTA FINAL:** Se me olvidaba mencionar que uno de los problemas que tengo es que no entiendo porque no se realizan los cambios de clase y ni siquiera se quitan las clases si estoy usando `addClass` y `removeClass`.

Comment: ¿Conoces Jquery? Con esto podras hacer lo que quieres pero de forma muy sencilla y rapida. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio conozco muy poco realmente, leeré lo que me compartiste, gracias

Comment: al menos linkea las cdns, en todo caso plantea un [ejemplo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no necesitas hacer tanta ida y vuelta entre elementos, revisa la función find() de jquery

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como podrías realizar lo es muy simple pero te podría ayudar, puedes declarar una variable para que sepas cuando tiene que ocultar y mostrar y usar un operador ternario para que realices la acción,

```
   var x = false;

    $("button").click(function(){
        var  btn =  x === false ?  true  :  false ;
        btn === true ? $("elementoID").hide(): $("elementoID").show();
    });
```

Comment: perfecto enrique, muchas gracias, al dar clic en el botón desaparece el contenido asociado, aunque al yo darle clic de nuevo no vuelve a aparecer el contenido, estoy intentando ver que puede ser y que cambios hacerle.